# Multiple texture loading issue in ZwoptexManager WiEngine Android

Tags: android

I am working on Wi-Engine and currently facing the issue while loading two sheets into zwoptex manager.

In the code below I am loading two sheets (sheeta and sheetb), with two animations which are stored as actions in class (firstAction, secondAction). Later when I runAction on the sprite on button click, the firstAction runs fine but the **secondAction uses the texture of firstAction with frames of second**, which causes unexpected result. kindly if you can let me know what I am missing or doing wrong.

`

```
/******** Loading Sheet 1********/


Texture2D tex = Texture2D.makePNG(R.drawable.sheeta);
ZwoptexManager.addZwoptex("sheeta", R.raw.sheeta,  tex);


/******** Loading Sheet 2********/


Texture2D tex2 = Texture2D.makePNG(R.drawable.sheetb);
ZwoptexManager.addZwoptex("sheetb",  R.raw.sheetb,tex2);


petSprite = ZwoptexManager.makeSprite("image_1.png"); // image_1 is in Sheeta

/******* Creating Animations and Actions    ******/
Animation firstAnimation = new Animation(0);

for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) 
{
    firstAnimation.addFrame(0.1f, ZwoptexManager.getFrameRect("sheeta",             "image_" + i + ".png"));
}


Animate a = (Animate)Animate.make(firstAnimation).autoRelease();
firstAction = (Action)Repeat.make(a, 2);

Animation secondAnimation = new Animation(0);

for (int i = 10; i <= 20; i++) 
{
    secondAnimation.addFrame(0.1f, ZwoptexManager.getFrameRect("sheetb",
                    "image_" + i + ".png"));
}
Animate b = (Animate)Animate.make(secondAnimation).autoRelease();
secondAction = (Action)Repeat.make(b, 1);
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is the proper way to get animations working, for those who are having the same problem.

```
Animation secondAnimation = new Animation(0);
for (int i = 52; i <= 65; i++) 
{
    SpriteFrame temp = ZwoptexManager.getSpriteFrame("sheetb","image_" + i + ".png");
    temp.setDuration(0.1f);
    secondAnimation.addFrame(temp);
}
Animate temp = (Animate)Animate.make(secondAnimation).autoRelease();
Action firstAction = (Action)Repeat.make(temp, 1);
```